# Run an gif animation only once on kivy

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

I wanted to make an `kivy app` which runs an `gif animation`.

The `gif animation` is supposed to be stopped after it runs once on the `application` start, but the `gif animation` is running over and over again and I don't know how to stop it.

Here is the code(the part which is important):

```
class level(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Feld(Widget):
    weg = StringProperty('test.gif')
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.ids.my_image.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            pass

Root = Builder.load_string('''
level:
    id: level
<level>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        id: box1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Feld:
            pos: 100, 310
            id: a1
<Feld>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        id: my_image
        source: root.weg

''')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set [anim_loop](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.HTML#kivy.uix.image.Image.anim_loop) property:

```
anim_loop                                                Added in 1.9.0

    Number of loops to play then stop animating. 0 means keep animating.

    anim_loop is a NumericProperty defaults to 0.
```

Comment: I set it in the kivy language:    anim_loop: 1