# Kivy Gif animation runs too often

Tags: python, kivy, gif, animated-gif

I wanted to make a kivy program with a gif animation which runs once and then stops.
I set anim_loop to 1 , but it keeps running over and over again.
Here is the code:

```
Root = Builder.load_string('''
  Image:
    source: 'streifen1.gif'
    size_hint_y: 1
    anim_loop: 1
''')


class TTT(App):
 def build(self):
    Window.clearcolor = (0, 0.5, 1, 1)# sets the backgroundcolor
    return Root #returnst the kv string and therefore the root widget`
```

Comment: Are you using kivy 1.9? And are you able to try a zip of your images instead of a gif, this may be better supported?

Comment: @inclement How am I supposed to do this, there is nothing about it in the docs: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html?highlight=image#kivy.uix.image

Comment: Make a zip file containing your images, and point your Image source at that filename.

Comment: @inclement, wish it were as easy as you describe, but I've tried it and no joy.  We're already in undocumented area, getting into witchcraft, now.  Kivy, help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anim_loop` property should work in Kivy 1.9.0, if you are using an older version then consider an upgrade.

There is also an another way. You can stop an animation using following code:

```
myimage._coreimage.anim_reset(False)
```

To stop an animation after it was played once observe the `texture` propery. It will be changed after loading each of the frames. If your GIF have n frames then stop the animation after (n+1)-th call of the `on_texture` method.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyImage(Image):
    frame_counter = 0
    frame_number = 2 # my example GIF had 2 frames

    def on_texture(self, instance, value):     
        if self.frame_counter == self.frame_number + 1:
            self._coreimage.anim_reset(False)
        self.frame_counter += 1


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyImage(source = "test.gif")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much,You cant imagen how much you have helped me

Comment: @Gilgamesch, I think I could help you sooner if you had answered to this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726524/run-an-gif-animation-only-once-on-kivy#comment49537709_30727495